# Getting error while generating image variations using openAI using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, error-handling, openai-api

I am working on a whatsapp bot with chatgpt like features like image generation, variation.
For now when someone sends an image in the test group chat, the image is saved in the local folder.

```
const saveToDir = async (bufferString) => {
  const bufferImage = Buffer.from(bufferString, "base64");
  fs.writeFile("sampleImage.png", bufferImage, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error saving image: ", err);
    } else {
      console.log("Image saved successfully");
    }
  });
};
```

When I use sampleImage.png to generate variations, I get the following error.
Code:

```
const GPTImageVariations = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await openai.createImageVariation(
      fs.createReadStream("sampleImage.png"),
      1,
      "512x512"
    );
    console.log(response.data.data[0].url);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.data);
    } else {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }
};
```

Error:
`400`

```
{
  error: {
    code: null,
    message: 'Uploaded image must be a PNG and less than 4 MB.',
    param: null,
    type: 'invalid_request_error'
  }
}
```

The uploaded image has the extension png and it's size if much less than 4MB.
I checked if my key was still valid and that was causing this issue but that wasn't the case.